# Show Progress When Uploading file to google drive in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-drive-api

How to show the progress, of files being uploaded to google drive in flutter? below is my code, how can I rewrite it to show the progress in percentage?

Not mean progress bar, I just want to show the progress percentage.
Thanks.

```
    await driveApi.files
            .create(
          fileToUpload,
          supportsAllDrives: true,
          uploadMedia: drive.Media(
            zipFile.openRead(),
            zipFile.lengthSync(),
          ),
        )
            .then((value) async {
          await zipFile.delete();
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              content: Text('File uploaded successfully'),
            ),
          );
        });
```

Comment: hey, Do you get the answer?

Comment: Mahi, @AnshRathod is there any work around?

Comment: @Nik found the way and ended up building my own plugin for google drive storage

Comment: I am also trying to make one. But it's been delayed. @Nik just like Ansh said.

Comment: can you share way that you have implemented? It's better for others who are getting same issue.